# What should be done if a question is better written, and gets better answers, than a mostly duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, questions, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310227/is-it-correct-to-say-turn-the-air-conditioner-up-down-when-we-want-the-air-con) was recently asked.  It's a well written question, and has attracted multiple good answers with a lot of explanation and nuance.  It looks like it will be a very useful resource for language learners in the future.

Unfortunately, the gist of the question is pretty much the same as [this older question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165887/use-of-the-word-lower).  However, the older question is awkwardly written, has misconceptions built into the wording of it, and various mistakes abound.  It also has only one answer which, while accurate, is barebones and devoid of nuance and explanation.

So the newer question is a duplicate... but it also seems to be the far better question overall, and more useful in every way.

Do we really have to close the newer question as duplicate in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting former Community Manager @Shog9:

> If the new question is a better quality question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one.

([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/295232))

Comment: Can I quote you next time an author moans at me for daring to close their much older question as a duplicate of a much newer one but with better answers. Please, tell me I can.

Comment: Better quote Shog9 :)

Comment: If you disagree with Shog9, now is your chance to say so!

Comment: I [disagreed with Jon Skeet once](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340875/4751173), that already felt uncomfortable ...